# Decorating a method

Tags: python, methods, decorator

In my Python app, I'm using events to communicate between different plugins.
Now, instead of registering the methods to the events manually, I thought I might use decorators to do that for me.

I would like to have it look like this:

```
@events.listento('event.name')
def myClassMethod(self, event):
    ...
```

I have first tried to do it like this:

```
def listento(to):
    def listen_(func):
        myEventManager.listen(to, func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return listen_
```

When I call`myEventManger.listen('event', self.method)`from within the instance, everything is running fine. However, if I use the decorator approach, the`self`argument is never passed.

The other approach that I have tried, after searching for a solution on the Internet, is to use a class as a decorator:

```
class listen(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
        myEventManager.listen('frontend.route.register', self)
        self._method = method
        self._name = method.__name__
        self._self = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        self._self = instance
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._method(self._self, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem with this approach is that I don't really understand the concept of`__get__`, and that I don't know how I'd incorporate the parameters.
Just for testing I have tried using a fixed event to listen to, but with this approach, nothing happens. When I add print statements, I can see that`__init__`is called.
If I add an additional, "old style" event registration, both`__get__`and`__call__`get executed, and the event works, despite the new decorator.

What would be the best way to achieve what I'm looking for, or am I just missing some important concept with decorators?

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be happier just calling `myEventManager.listen('frontend.route.register', myClassMethod)` after you've defined the method?  Since you're not modifying the behavior of the method at all, I'm not sure decorators are the best fit here.

Comment: I would have liked to see directly from the method definition which method is registered to what event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator approach isn't working because the decorator is being called when the class is constructed, not when the instance is constructed. When you say

```
class Foo(object):
  @some_decorator
  def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # etc etc
```

then `some_decorator` will be called when the class Foo is constructed, and it will be passed an *unbound* method, not the bound method of an instance. That's why `self` isn't getting passed.

The second method, on the other hand, could work as long as you only ever create *one* object of each class you use the decorator on, *and* if you're a bit clever. If you define `listen` as above and then define

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.some_method = self.some_method # SEE BELOW FOR EXPLANATION
    # etc etc
  @listen
  def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # etc etc
```

Then `listen.__get__` would be called when someone tried to call `f.some_method` directly for some `f`...but the whole point of your scheme is that no-one's doing that! The event call back mechanism is calling the `listen` instance directly 'cause that's what it gets passed and the `listen` instance is calling the unbound method it squirrelled away when it was created. `listen.__get__` won't ever get called and the `_self` parameter is never getting set properly...*unless* you explicitly access `self.some_method` yourself, as I did in the `__init__` method above. Then `listen.__get__` will be called upon instance creation and `_self` will be set properly.

Problem is (a) this is a horrible, horrible hack and (b) if you try to create two instances of `Foo` then the second one will overwrite the `_self` set by the first, because there's still only one `listen` object being created, and that's associated to the class, not the instance. If you only ever use one `Foo` instance then you're fine, but if you have to have the event trigger two different `Foo`'s then you'll just have to use your "old style" event registration.

The TL,DR version: decorating a method decorates the *unbound* method of the class, whereas you want your event manager to get passed the *bound* method of an instance.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! So there is no uhm let's call it proper way to do, what I'm looking for?

Comment: Not that I know of. The "class as a decorator with `__get__`" trick you found decorates a method, kind of, if you only access the method as `f.some_method()`, but that technique has limits, one of which you just happened to find on your first try.

Answer (score 3):

Part of your code is:

```
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func
```

which defines `wrapper` then completely ignores it and returns `func` instead.  Hard to say whether this is a real problem in your real code because obviously you're not posting that (as proven by typoes such as `myEventManagre`, `myEvnetManager`, &c), but if that's what you're doing in your actual code it **is** obviously part of your problem.

Comment: I just invented something for the event registering, so it was clear what was meant :) sorry, for the sloppy writing, it was very early... anyway, you are right, that is an actual error that I didn't spot (wrapper vs func). However, in the end it doesn't make a difference, since I don't want to be changing the method at all, so I could as well omit the wrapper completely.