# Decorating method (class methods overloading)

Tags: python, methods, python-3.x, decorator

Inspired by Muhammad Alkarouri answer in [What are good uses for Python3's "Function Annotations"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038033/what-are-good-uses-for-python3s-function-annotations) , I want to do this `multimethod` for methods, not regular functions. However, when I do this

```
registry = {}

class MultiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.typemap = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        types = tuple(arg.__class__ for arg in args) # a generator expression!
        function = self.typemap.get(types)
    if function is None:
        raise TypeError("no match")
    return function(*args)
def register(self, types, function):
    if types in self.typemap:
        raise TypeError("duplicate registration")
    self.typemap[types] = function

def multimethod(function):
    name = function.__name__
    mm = registry.get(name)
    if mm is None:
        mm = registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)
    types = tuple(function.__annotations__.values())
    mm.register(types, function)
    return mm

class A:
@multimethod
def foo(self, a: int):
    return "an int"

a = A() 
print( a.foo( 1 ) )
```

I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    print( a.foo( 1 ) )
  File "test.py", line 12, in __call__
    return function(*args)
TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Which seems to be expected, as explained in [Decorating a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401421/decorating-a-method) , because of the `self` argument.

But I have no idea how to make it work. Well, when I remove the "self", it's working (almost) fine, but I don't want to remove it. Please note, that I'm doing this for practice, I know that there are some libs, providing method overloading.

What I tried:

- very silly, but wanted to try - added parameter `self` in `def multimethod( function )` - the same error
- I thought about adding in the `__init__` of `class MultiMethod` a third parameter - `obj` and stored `self` as member, but I can't do this through `multimethod` as it is a function.
- I don't want to add parameters for the decorator, so this options (if possible at all) is ignored

I read several similar questions, but didn't find what I was looking for. I'm pretty sure this is dummy question, but I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem you have is that you use a class in place of a function. There is no mechanism to bind that class to the instance it's called from, unlike a function where this happens automatically.

In short, when you do `a.foo( .. )` it returns a `MultiMethod`, but this object has no idea that it is supposed to be bound to `a`.

You have to pass in the instance in some way or another. One easy way is to wrap it all in a function and let Python do it's thing:

```
registry = {}

class MultiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.typemap = {}

    # self = a MultiMethod instance, instance = the object we want to bind to
    def __call__(self, instance, *args):
        types = tuple(arg.__class__ for arg in args) # a generator expression!
        function = self.typemap.get(types)

        if function is None:
            raise TypeError("no match")
        return function(instance, *args)

    def register(self, types, function):
        if types in self.typemap:
            raise TypeError("duplicate registration")
        self.typemap[types] = function

def multimethod(function):
    name = function.__name__
    mm = registry.get(name)
    if mm is None:
        mm = registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)

    types = tuple(function.__annotations__.values())
    mm.register(types, function)
    # return a function instead of a object - Python binds this automatically
    def getter(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        return mm(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    return getter

class A:
    @multimethod
    def foo(self, a: int):
        return "an int", a

a = A() 
print( a.foo( 1 ) )
```

The more complex way would be to write your own descriptor on the `A` class that does this binding.