# Decorate method with decorator class

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a wrapper for methods.
The decorator itself is implemented as a class that overwrites the `__call__` method.

This works for decorating functions, but if a method is decorated this way, `self` is not bound to the decorated function.

The following is a minimal example:

```
import functools


class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("PreBar")
        result = self.__func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("PostBar")
        return result


def MyDecorator(func):
    return Wrapper(func)


class Foo:
    baz = "Baz"

    @MyDecorator
    def bar(self):
        print(self.baz)
        return self.baz


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.bar)
    print(f"Result of foo.bar(): {foo.bar()}")

    print(Foo.bar)
    print(f"Result of Foo.bar(foo): {Foo.bar(foo)}")
```

This produces the following error, meaning that self is not automatically passed to the `__call__`  invocation as with normal methods:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mypath/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(f"Result of foo.bar(): {foo.bar()}")
  File "/mypath/test.py", line 14, in __call__
    result = self.__func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Question: How can the returned callable wrapper object be bound to `self`?
Wrapping the object in a function to let python do the binding is an option, but not in my case, since the actual object is needed.

The question [How can I decorate an instance method with a decorator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104047) is similar to what i want to achieve. The solution provided there works if only the binding is required. What i require though, is that the object instance that is returned when accessing the attribute is of type `Wrapper`, not of type `functools.partial`.

The [second answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104964/5709170) also does not work, since the instance returned by `__get__` is of type `method` and not `Wrapper`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decorate an instance method with a decorator class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104047/how-can-i-decorate-an-instance-method-with-a-decorator-class)

Comment: What's the point of `MyDecorator`? You could decorate `bar` with `Wrapper` directly.

Comment: @chepner You are right. I could have omitted the function for my minimal example. The original code uses a class MyDecorator, because the decorator takes parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The following post addresses the Problem by simply wrapping the object in a function such that python can bind `self` with the native mechanism: [Decorating method (class methods overloading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009344/decorating-method-class-methods-overloading)

As mentioned in the question this is not an option for me. The post also mentions the alternative: Implement the descriptor protocol for the `Wrapper` class. The question [Decorating a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401421/decorating-a-method) addresses this as well.
The problem there is, that the approach used there only works with one instance of the class.

I came up with the following solution:

```
import functools


class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, func, instance=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.__func = func
        self.__instance = instance
        self.__bindings = {}
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("PreBar")
        if self.__instance is not None:
            args =(self.__instance, ) + args
        result = self.__func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("PostBar")
        return result

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            return self.__bindings[(instance, owner)]
        except KeyError:
            binding = self.__bindings[(instance, owner)] = Wrapper(self.__func, instance)
            return binding


def MyDecorator(func):
    return Wrapper(func)


class Foo:
    baz = "Baz"

    @MyDecorator
    def bar(self):
        print(self.baz)
        return self.baz


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.bar)
    print(f"Result of foo.bar(): {foo.bar()}")

    print(Foo.bar)
    print(f"Result of Foo.bar(foo): {Foo.bar(foo)}")
```

The difference being that the `__get__` method for function descriptors creates a new Wrapper instance for each (instance, owner) pair.
This way the wrapper is always bound to exactly one instance, or even the class itself.