# Decorating an instance method of a class with a decorating function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am using Python 3.10. Consider this toy example of a cache that caches the very first call to an instance method and then returns the cached value on subsequent calls:

```
import functools

def cache(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)  # for __name__
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrapper.cache:
            print("caching...")
            wrapper.cache = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper.cache
    wrapper.cache = None
    return wrapper

class Power:
    def __init__(self, exponent):
        self.exponent = exponent
    @cache
    def of(self, base):
        return base ** self.exponent

# test
>>> cube = Power(3)
>>> cube.of(2)
caching...
8
>>> cube.of.cache
8
>>> cube.of.__dict__
{'__wrapped__': <function __main__.Power.of(self, base)>, 'cache': 8}
>>> cube.of.cache = None
...
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'cache'
```

I have two questions:

1.) The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401421/decorating-a-method?rq=3) says that the `@cache` decorator runs when the `Power` class is constructed and it will be passed an *unbound* method (`of` in my case). I guess this claim is true only when you decorate an instance method with a class decorator. There it is an issue that you would need a reference of the `cube` object to be stored in the decorating class instance construction, but that `cube` instance is not defined yet. I am having trouble reconciling this claim with the fact that my example works; the decorated `of` method is passed a tuple with the first element being the `cube` instance and the second the `base=2` parameter

2.) I can access the `.cache` attribute but why can't I reset it? It gives `AttributeError`.

Comment: `cube.of` is a `method` object that wraps `Power.of`. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this "working". Hint: what happens if you also define `square = Power(2)` and ask for `square.of(2)` after previously asking for `cube.of(2)`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I just did it myself before looking at your comment. Yes, I see, `.cache` works like a class attribute, shared across all `Power` instances - not good

Comment: Indeed. The underlying function is decorated (this happens even before the class is created), not the bound methods (which are created later).

Comment: I took the idea from [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#fancy-decorators), where standalone/unbound functions are decorated by sticking a counter attribute to the wrapper. There it works. For bound methods it does not. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that the decorating mechanism assigns the result of `cache(of)` to `Power.of`. So it is `Power` which has the attribute `of` (your cache decorator).

You can write: `Power.of.cache = None` to get what you want:

```
cube = Power(3)
print(cube.of(2))
print(cube.of(2))

Power.of.cache = None
print(cube.of(2))
```

Output:

```
caching...
8
8
caching...
8
```

Comment: Great explanation. So when `@cache` runs in the definition of `Power` it can only assign the result to `Power.of` as there is no instance yet. This explains the class-wide nature of `.cache`, the fact that it will be shared by all instances yet to be instantiated. IIRC, attributes of `Power` can be accessed through its instances, which is what I see on printing `cube.of.cache`. But it does not directly belong to `cube`. It explains the `AttributeError`. I would have to assign (something) to `cube.of` first, then another (something) to `cube.of.cache`, to really have something on `cube` ...

Answer (score 2):

Since 2) is easier to answer, I'll start with that one.
It is actually directly answered in the [documentation for methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#methods):

> Like function objects, bound method objects support getting arbitrary attributes.
> However, since method attributes are actually stored on the underlying function
> object (`method.__func__`), **setting method attributes on bound methods is disallowed**.

As, can be easily verified,

```
cube.of.__func__.cache = None
```

does in fact work with your example.

Now in regards to 1), you do not need an instance to be able to run the decorator - "calling the decorator" does not mean calling the function that is being decorated. It refers to the process of taking this function, wrapping it with some additional functionality and returning in place of the original function. It will only be called when you actually call decorated function, and that's when arguments need to be defined and will be eventually passed to `of` (or ommited if cache is already defined).

Comment: In light of the other comments and answer this must be just another way to access and write the class-level `Power.of.cache` attribute from the `cube` instance. Good to know about it. But contrary to what this line of code suggests, `.cache` does not directly belong to `cube`

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos I did not suggest that it belongs to `cube`. As the docs say, it belongs to underlying function object referred to by `__func__`.

Comment: @AndrasVanyolos Another thing, this attribute is not class level. If you subclass `Power`, you will see that subclass shares the cache with it.